# Access libvirt+KVM virtual machines with DNS

Tags: domain-name-system, kvm-virtualization, internal-dns, libvirt, dnsmasq

I have an Ubuntu Trusty machine running KVM + Libvirt to manage small virtual machines, and using the standard NetworkManager to connect to regular networks.

I want to be able to access the virtual machines via DNS from the host.

Libvirt uses a virtual private subnet (192.168.122.0/24), NAT'd to access the rest of the world via a bridge (virbr0) on my eth0. Dnamasq priveds DHCP+DNS to this virtual network.

This is the libvirt config for the virtual network:

```
<network>
  <name>default</name>
  <uuid>400c59ff-c276-4154-ab73-9a8a8d1c6be3</uuid>
  <forward mode='nat'>
    <nat>
      <port start='1024' end='65535'/>
    </nat>
  </forward>
  <bridge name='virbr0' stp='on' delay='0'/>
  <mac address='52:54:00:f4:bd:37'/>
  <domain name='kvm'/>
  <dns forwardPlainNames='no'>
    <forwarder addr='127.0.1.1'/>
    <host ip='192.168.122.1'>
      <hostname>host</hostname>
      <hostname>host.kvm</hostname>
    </host>
  </dns>
  <ip address='192.168.122.1' netmask='255.255.255.0'>
    <dhcp>
      <range start='192.168.122.2' end='192.168.122.254'/>
    </dhcp>
  </ip>
</network>
```

Libvirt starts a dnsmasq instance listening on 192.168.122.1:53 which answers all requests for .knv and forwards any other requests to my host. This dnsmasq config is automatically generated by libvirt:

**/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/default.conf**

```
##WARNING:  THIS IS AN AUTO-GENERATED FILE. CHANGES TO IT ARE LIKELY TO BE
##OVERWRITTEN AND LOST.  Changes to this configuration should be made using:
##    virsh net-edit default
## or other application using the libvirt API.
##
## dnsmasq conf file created by libvirt
strict-order
user=libvirt-dnsmasq
no-resolv
server=127.0.1.1
domain=kvm
expand-hosts
domain-needed
local=//
pid-file=/var/run/libvirt/network/default.pid
except-interface=lo
bind-dynamic
interface=virbr0
dhcp-range=192.168.122.2,192.168.122.254
dhcp-no-override
dhcp-leasefile=/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/default.leases
dhcp-lease-max=253
dhcp-hostsfile=/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/default.hostsfile
addn-hosts=/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/default.addnhosts
```

NetworkManager has an instance of dnsmasq listening on 127.0.1.1:53 which it uses for all DNS quieries before passing to whichever DNS servers my host gets assigned by the external DHCP system.

In order for my host Ubuntu system to use the dnsmasq of libvirt, I point the dnsmasq of NetworkManager to use 192.168.122.1 for the domain kvm:

**/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d/libvirt.conf**

```
server=/kvm/192.168.122.1
```

And this works, for the most part...

```
me@host ~ $ ps aufx
...cut...
root     11010  0.2  0.0 342084  6348 ?        Ssl  10:59   0:00 NetworkManager
root     11018  0.0  0.0  10232  3732 ?        S    10:59   0:00  \_ /sbin/dhclient -d -sf /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action -pf /run/sendsigs.omit.d/network-manager.dhclient-eth0.pid -lf /var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient-b8043 
nobody   11228  0.0  0.0  32252  1564 ?        S    10:59   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --no-resolv --keep-in-foreground --no-hosts --bind-interfaces --pid-file=/run/sendsigs.omit.d/network-manager.dnsmasq.pid --listen-address=127.0.1.1 --
root     11033  1.0  0.1 513356 15160 ?        Sl   10:59   0:01 /usr/sbin/libvirtd -d
libvirt+ 11085  0.0  0.0  28208   948 ?        S    10:59   0:00 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --conf-file=/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/default.conf

me@host ~ $ sudo netstat -nulpd | grep dnsmasq
udp  0  0  127.0.1.1:53      0.0.0.0:*  11228/dnsmasq   
udp  0  0  192.168.122.1:53  0.0.0.0:*  11085/dnsmasq   
udp  0  0  0.0.0.0:67        0.0.0.0:*  11085/dnsmasq  

me@host ~ $ host test.kvm
test.kvm has address 192.168.122.193
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

But creates a massive number of dnsmasq AAAA queries all waiting for a response.

```
me@host ~ $ sudo netstat -nulpd | grep dnsmasq
udp  0  0  0.0.0.0:39329  0.0.0.0:*  11228/dnsmasq   
udp  0  0  0.0.0.0:2469   0.0.0.0:*  11085/dnsmasq   
udp  0  0  0.0.0.0:14805  0.0.0.0:*  11228/dnsmasq
...cut...
udp  0  0  0.0.0.0:51569  0.0.0.0:*  11228/dnsmasq   
udp  0  0  0.0.0.0:31091  0.0.0.0:*  11085/dnsmasq   
udp  0  0  0.0.0.0:39305  0.0.0.0:*  11085/dnsmasq

me@host ~ $ sudo netstat -nulpd | grep dnsmasq | wc -l
131
```

And a tcpdump shows them to be mainly AAAA requests:

```
me@host ~ $ sudo tcpdump -vni any udp port 53
tcpdump: listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked), capture size 65535 bytes
11:04:49.453864 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 56217, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 55)
    127.0.0.1.58535 > 127.0.1.1.53: 31275+ A? mysql.kvm. (27)
11:04:49.453948 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 20062, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 55)
    192.168.122.1.7098 > 192.168.122.1.53: 41491+ A? mysql.kvm. (27)
11:04:49.454013 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 20063, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 71)
    192.168.122.1.53 > 192.168.122.1.7098: 41491* 1/0/0 mysql.kvm. A 192.168.122.193 (43)
11:04:49.454068 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 37088, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 71)
    127.0.1.1.53 > 127.0.0.1.58535: 31275* 1/0/0 mysql.kvm. A 192.168.122.193 (43)
11:04:49.454321 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 56218, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 55)
    127.0.0.1.56040 > 127.0.1.1.53: 47999+ AAAA? mysql.kvm. (27)
11:04:49.454381 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 20064, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 55)
    192.168.122.1.19631 > 192.168.122.1.53: 20542+ AAAA? mysql.kvm. (27)
...cut...
11:05:09.510237 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 20515, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 55)
    192.168.122.1.19631 > 192.168.122.1.53: 35761+ MX? mysql.kvm. (27)
11:05:09.510237 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 56674, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 55)
    127.0.0.1.46085 > 127.0.1.1.53: 53641+ AAAA? mysql.kvm. (27)
11:05:09.510315 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 56675, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 55)
    127.0.0.1.46085 > 127.0.1.1.53: 26166+ MX? mysql.kvm. (27)
11:05:09.510334 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 20516, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 55)
    192.168.122.1.19631 > 192.168.122.1.53: 4247+ AAAA? mysql.kvm. (27)
11:05:09.510407 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 56676, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 55)
    127.0.0.1.46085 > 127.0.1.1.53: 49331+ AAAA? mysql.kvm. (27)
11:05:09.510433 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 20517, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 55)
    192.168.122.1.19631 > 192.168.122.1.53: 63294+ MX? mysql.kvm. (27)
^C
934 packets captured
1857 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

I tried lowering the priority of AAAA records in **/etc/gai.conf**

```
precedence ::ffff:0:0/96  100
```

Even tried disabling IPv6 entirely **/etc/sysctl.conf**:

```
# Disable IPv6
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

But the AAAA requests are still being sent and name resolution becomes unbearably slow.

Is there a way for either libvirt or NetworkManager to ignore or respond negatively to these requests so I don't have to wait for all the requests to time out before using the A record that was already received?

Answer (score 3):

If a forwarder is configured, dnsmasq will forward all DNS queries that it has no explicit data for. This includes records for configured static DHCP clients that have no active lease, AAAA records unless IPv6 addresses are defined explicitly, and more.

There are several ways to avoid this:

### Don't configure a forwarder

Simply omit the fowarder entries in the network definition. Probably not desirable, unless the virtual network is **really** isolated. This is the only possibility that libvirt currently supports (12/2014), AFAIK.

### local domain in dnsmasq.conf

Configure the domain as "local" in dnsmasq:

```
 domain=local.net,192.168.10.0/24
 local=/local.net/
 local=/10.168.192.in-addr.arpa/
```

In theory, this could be abbreviated as `domain=local.net,192.168.10.0/24,local`, but [a dnsmasq bug fixed only recently](http://thekelleys.org.uk/gitweb/?p=dnsmasq.git;a=commit;h=3ad3f3bbd4ee716a7d2fb1e115cf89bd1b1a5de9) causes this to fail.

libvirt doesn't support this. In order to use this configuration, you need to set up the bridge manually in your OS and configure the libvirt network like this:

```
   <network>
     <name>local</name>
     <forward mode='bridge'/>
     <bridge name='br0'/>
   </network>
```

You don't have to create a libvirt virtual network at all in this configuration, just use `<interface 'type=bridge'>` in your VM definition files.

### auth zone in dnsmasq.conf

The `auth-zone` parameter has a similar effect to `local`. However it has other implications that I don't claim to fully understand. I suppose this configuration would be desirable if names in the virtual network are supposed to be resolved from the outside.

```
domain=local.net
auth-zone=local.net
```

This setup isn't supported by libvirt either, so the same procedure for setting up the bridge must be applied as above.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's two positive goals for a DNS setup like this:

- Resolving `name.vm` on the host (and in a guest) should return the IP address for the VM called `name`
- Resolving `example.com` in the guest (and on the host) should return the IP address for example.com

Straightforwardly pointing the host resolver at the dnsmasq instance for the guest network as a forwarder, and the dnsmasq for the guest network at the host resolver, will result in unknown hosts bouncing back and forth and hanging.

This suggests two issues to avoid:

- Resolving a nonexistent VM (or the AAAA record for an existent, IPv4-only VM) should promptly return NXDOMAIN/nodata
- Resolving a nonexistent hostname (nonexistent.example.com) should also promptly return NXDOMAIN/nodata

Resolving `name.vm` at all is achieved by putting `<domain name='vm' localOnly='yes'/>` in the libvirtd network configuration (`virsh net-edit default` or whatever). I believe `name='vm'` is both (a) the search domain handed out over DHCP and (b) gets appended to DHCP hostnames to generate the FQDN that `dnsmasq` uses to put VMs in DNS. Setting `localOnly` means that if a name doesn't appear in the local zone, `dnsmasq` won't ask the upstream server -- this is the key setting to prevent `dig name.vm AAAA` looping.

Making `name.vm` resolve from the host depends on the host's resolver configuration. If using `systemd-resolved`, try `resolvectl dns virbr0 192.168.122.1; resolvectl domain virbr0 vm; resolvectl default-route virbr0 no'`. The first piece tells `systemd-resolved` to use the guest network's dnsmasq as a resolver. The second piece says the search domain associated with that interface is `vm`. With just these pieces, the host can successfully resolve `name.vm` and `example.com`. However, the third piece tells `systemd-resolved` to only use the guest network DNS server for the configured domains -- without this, lookups for `nonexistent.example.com` will loop between the host and guest network DNS resolvers.

(FWIW, another way to make `name.vm` ~resolve is with the libvirt NSS module https://libvirt.org/nss.html, though that doesn't use DNS as such and I haven't tried it.)

Comment: I think the "localOnly" setting I mention in my answer is "local domain" approach mentioned in the other answer (https://serverfault.com/a/653262/531369) -- looks like libvirtd added support in the last decade or so.